# Validating CSV file prior to import into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, validation, parsing, csv

I know there are other threads around this topic but they're not quite as specific as my needs (that I can so far find).

I have csv files for import into an SQL Server database I manage. They are put together by humans and so may have errors like too many columns, incorrect data types, corrupt headers and so on.

I have a web form that can receive files from users to a directory on the server and then it reads a line in as a string, parses it cell by cell and does things like checking the correct cell count exists, then moves onto the next line.

Now onto validating the data type and ranges, which I am unclear on the best method. Doing things like manual range checks for numeric types seems a bit archaic.

Is there a better way? A few things;

1. I have SQL Server types like "numeric" but also nvarchar.
2. The files can be as small as a few kilobytes or as large as over a gigabyte.
3. I need to report each specific row and column where an error exists, not just row x failed.

I thought maybe trying to convert/cast the cell value to the expected type, catching exceptions and splitting the data into chunks and spawn threads to do checks in parallel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel you should you SSIS if you data store is SQL Server. Create an SSIS package and try to execute SSIS package using C# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28096/Excecute-SSIS-package-DTSX-from-ASP-Net this will take care of mappings of columns to particular datatype.

Comment: Is the site MVC3?  If so, have a look at models/viewmodels and data/validation annotations.  You can then create a new ObjectX, populate it from CSV row and validate it - finding out if the row (entire object) and properties are valid, report back accordingly and save if suitable.

Comment: This is just a standard ASP.Net C# web application. I am hopeful to retain the validation within the webapp itself so that I am not hindered by database outages and/or maintenance windows. Is there a better way within the C# code?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use bulc copy. 
SSIS is much more complicated and error prone (and under normal circumstances also much slower...).

Normally you know which columns you expect and you want to create a "import-stage table" for the imported data that has the correct format. You can reject the complete file if it does not fit the minimal requirements (column count) in TSQL (with "try/catch" around the bulc insert).

Conversions and type checks can be done after the initial import. For this it may be useful to have additional columns at the stage table with the correct format. E.g. you can import into a nvarchar column and convert to a decimal value. The trick here is to use a view: in the excample below the view "myImportTable_InsertView" selects only the imported columns from the stage table (stage table has more columns for type checking)

```
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(4000) =

    INSERT dbo.myImportTable_InsertView
    FROM ''' + @FullFilename + ''' WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
    CODEPAGE= ''RAW''
    )'
    Exec (@SQLString)
```

After finishing all validations you will simply copy the data from the stage table to it's final destination.

To report errorenous rows I usually use flags on the stage table rows to mark different kinds of errors.